# Select menu disturbs screen resolution on iphone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

When I tried to select a value using jQuery Mobile select menu, it disturbs the screen resolution.

Is there any Javascript solution like `window.resize()` to overcome this problem.

Comment: what do you mean by _disturb_?

Comment: It zooms the screen content, which i have to manually resize the window to normal size